# Deserialization from XML to List Object

Tags: c#, xml-deserialization

I am doing the program in convert XML file to List Objects. I have successfully done serialization from List to XML .but I have an problem on doing deserialization. Please anyone tell me what's the wrong i have done in this code.

This is my XML code.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Contact_x0020_Form xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <Contact>
    <Contact>
      <Id>1</Id>
      <Name>vicky1kumar</Name>
      <Phone>248847227</Phone>
    </Contact>
    <Contact>
      <Id>2</Id>
      <Name>vicky1kumar2kumar</Name>
      <Phone>725228355</Phone>
    </Contact>
    <Contact>
      <Id>3</Id>
      <Name>vicky1kumar2kumar3kumar</Name>
      <Phone>2032848116</Phone>
    </Contact>
    <Contact>
      <Id>4</Id>
      <Name>vicky1kumar2kumar3kumar4kumar</Name>
      <Phone>853938969</Phone>
    </Contact>
    <Contact>
      <Id>5</Id>
      <Name>vicky1kumar2kumar3kumar4kumar5kumar</Name>
      <Phone>530646891</Phone>
    </Contact>
  </Contact>
  <Id>0</Id>
</Contact_x0020_Form>
```

This is my Class for convert XML to List Object

```
public class Converter
{
    public static T XmlToObject<T>(string xml)
    {
        using (var xmlStream = new StringReader(xml))
        {
            var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
            return (T)serializer.Deserialize(XmlReader.Create(xmlStream));
        }
    }

    public static List<T> XmlToObjectList<T>(string xml, string nodePath)
    {
        var xmlDocument = new XmlDocument();
        xmlDocument.LoadXml(xml);

        var returnItemsList = new List<T>();

        foreach (XmlNode xmlNode in xmlDocument.SelectNodes(nodePath))
        {
            returnItemsList.Add(XmlToObject<T>(xmlNode.OuterXml));
        }
        return returnItemsList;
    }
}
```

And this is my DEserialization code...

```
List<string> decont = new List<string>();
decont  = Converter.XmlToObjectList<string>(@"C:\vignesh\serialization\xmlserialize\XmlSerializeContact.xml","//Contact");
                    foreach (var item in decont)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(decont);
                    }
```

I got this error:

> Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1.

Comment: Dharani @see my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, your xml should look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Contact_x0020_Form>
  <Contacts>
    <Contact>
      <Id>1</Id>
      <Name>vicky1kumar</Name>
      <Phone>248847227</Phone>
    </Contact>
    <Contact>
      <Id>2</Id>
      <Name>vicky1kumar2kumar</Name>
      <Phone>725228355</Phone>
    </Contact>
  </Contacts>
</Contact_x0020_Form>
```

Second, define `serialization classes` something like :

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "Contact_x0020_Form")]
public class Root
{
    [XmlElement("Contacts")]
    public Contacts contacts{get;set;}
}


public class Contacts
{
  public List<Contact> contacts {get;set;}
}

public class Contact
{
[XmlElement("Id")]
public int Id {get;set;}
[XmlElement("Name")]
public string Name {get;set;}
[XmlElement("Phone")]
public string Phone {get;set;}
}
```

and your `helper classes`

```
public static class serialize
{
public static T Deserialize<T>(string path)
        {
            T result;
            using (var stream = File.Open(path, FileMode.Open))
            {
                result = Deserialize<T>(stream);
            }
            return result;
        }

public static void Serialize<T>(T root, string path)
        {
            using (var stream = File.Open(path, FileMode.Create))
            {
                var xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
                xmlSerializer.Serialize(stream, root);
            }
        }

public static T Deserialize<T>(Stream stream)
        {

            var xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
            return (T)xmlSerializer.Deserialize(stream);
        }
}
```

And, finally your func:

```
static void Main()
    {
        var a = serialize.Deserialize<Root>("input.xml"); //xml file name given here.
        Console.WriteLine(a.contacts);
    }
```

This is how you should proceed. Then on, you can get the list of objects that you want.

Answer (score 1):

> Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1.

To address this first error, you must understand the cause. The issue is [`LoadXml`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.loadxml%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) accepts an xml string; whereas you are passing a path to an Xml file. You need to use [`Load`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.load%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead of `LoadXml`.

That said, there are a lot of other things you need to correct. The *serialized* XML provided in your question seems to be incorrect--e.g. the `Contact` node is its own parent. Thus, your node selection is giving you the entire Xml. (Did you mean to define `Contacts` node to be the parent of the `Contact` list?)

```
<Contacts>
.. <Contact>
```

Comment: Ya You are right... I gave it as LoadXml instead of Load..It's My mistake.but again i got the error on this Line..                return (T)serializer.Deserialize(XmlReader.Create(xmlStream));             error is: There is an error in XML document (1, 2).

Answer (score -1):

use this before calling xml data in deserialization

```
xml = Regex.Replace(xml, "<\\?xml.*?>", String.Empty);
```

here xml is your xml data.

Comment: what is the point of doing this ? what are you trying to achieve ?